# How do I use an image which is stored in Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm building an app which allows the user to upload their own images, to use within the app. I'm using the Firebase Cloudstore database to store the information on each image, and Firebase Storage to store the actual images.

So, the images are stored in Firebase Storage in a folder called images; within that, they are given a randomly generated name, which is stored in the appropriate record in the database. Let's say the name of a particular image is "abcd.png", then the database record will look like this:

```
symbols 
  > key1 > name: "Test symbol"
           uid: "User's randomly generated ID"
           description: "A description, as set by the user"
           url: "images/abcd.png"
```

Now, I want to show all the User's uploaded images as tiny thumbnails. I'm connecting to the database, finding all symbols which belong to the current user, and then using an ArrayAdapter to display them.  Unfortunately, I'm currently getting a row of blank boxes.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The symbols are shown in a Fragment called CurrentSymbolsFragment.  The layout (fragment_current_symbols.xml) is:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_symbolList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    </GridView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the class file is:

```
public class FragmentCurrentSymbols extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<ChartSymbol>           mSymbols;
    private Context             mContext;
    private GridView            mGridCurrentSymbols;

    static public FragmentCurrentSymbols newInstance(Context context,
                                                     ArrayList<ChartSymbol> symbols) {

        if(context == null)         return null;
        if(symbols == null)         return null;
        if(symbols.size() == 0)     return null;

        FragmentCurrentSymbols f = new FragmentCurrentSymbols();
        f.setRequiredData(context, symbols);

        return f;
    }

    public void setRequiredData(Context context, ArrayList<ChartSymbol> symbols) {

        if(context == null)         return;
        if(symbols == null)         return;
        if(symbols.size() == 0)     return;

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mSymbols = symbols;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_symbols, container, false);

        mGridCurrentSymbols = rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_symbolList)

        initialiseWithSymbols();

        return rootView;
    }

    // Set symbols to be shown and initialise the view
    public void setSymbols(ArrayList<ChartSymbol> symbols) {
        mSymbols = symbols;
        initialiseWithSymbols();
    }

    /**
     * initialiseWithSymbols
     * Initialise the symbol list from the symbols
     * This takes the symbols and shows them, in order, in the grid
     **/
    public void initialiseWithSymbols() {

        if (mSymbols == null) return;

        // Now set up ChartSymbolAdapter to display symbols in grid
        ChartSymbolAdapter mSymbolAdapter = new ChartSymbolAdapter(mContext,
                R.layout.adapter_symbol_manage_layout,
                mSymbols);
        mGridCurrentSymbols.setAdapter(mSymbolAdapter);
        mGridCurrentSymbols.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
```

The `ChartSymbolAdapter` class is:

```
public class ChartSymbolAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChartSymbol> {

    private Context                 mContext;
    private ArrayList<ChartSymbol>  mSymbolArray;
    private int                     layoutId;
    private ChartSymbol             selectedSymbol;

    public ChartSymbolAdapter(Context context, int layout_id, ArrayList<ChartSymbol> symbolArray) {
        super(context, layout_id, symbolArray);

        this.mContext=context;
        this.mSymbolArray=symbolArray;
        this.layoutId = layout_id;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private SymbolCell symbolCell;
        private TextView   symbolName, symbolKey;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        if(convertView == null) {
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert layoutInflater != null;
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.symbolCell = convertView.findViewById(R.id.symbol_cell);
            mViewHolder.symbolName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.symbol_name);
            mViewHolder.symbolKey = convertView.findViewById(R.id.symbol_key);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            // Now add the symbol
            ChartSymbol cellSymbol = mSymbolArray.get(position);
            // Find the url
            String drawableUrl = cellSymbol.getUrl();
            // If there's a Url, use it
            if(drawableUrl != null) {
                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(drawableUrl)
                            .into(mViewHolder.symbolCell);
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The `SymbolCell` class extends `ImageView`:

```
public class SymbolCell extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    ChartSymbol symbol;
    Paint paint;

    public SymbolCell(Context thisContext, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(thisContext, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();

    }

    /**
     * onDraw
     * Draw a square to contain the given symbol.
     * @param canvas Canvas to draw on
     */
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draw a box around cell
        // Set paint
        int stroke_width = 2;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke_width);

        float height = getHeight();
        float width = getWidth();

        // Draw a black border for item
        paint.setColor(0xff000000);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width - 2*stroke_width, height - 2*stroke_width, paint);

    }

}
```

When I try this out, I get a series of blank boxes.  There are as many boxes as I have symbols stored, so that's correct, but they're not showing the actual image. I've made sure that I'm using images which have colours going right to the edges, so that's not the issue.

This is the first time I've used Glide in a project, so am I doing something wrong there?

Using the debugger, I can see that the symbols are retrieved correctly from Firestore, and that the URL is correct. I'm not sure how to check whether Glide is actually connecting to the storage to find the image, but it's certainly not showing it.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46020245/549372

Comment: Is the url valid? "images/abcd.png" does not seem like a valid url.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I tried making changes according to that link, but I'm still getting blank squares.

Comment: bensadiku, good point!  I've replaced that with a url which directly leads to an image (by setting drawableUrl = "http://schindlersfabrics.com/images/Opera_Red_Floral_Scroll_Upholstery_fabric_8_.JPG" (just to eliminate that as a potential problem)), but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Each image in Cloud Storage has a gs (Google Storage) URL and is of course NOT PUBLICLY accessible, which means you have to get a download link first.

Do this by using the Firebase Storage SDK.

1. [Do the normal setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start)
2. [Get a storage app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getInstance())
3. [Get a reference to your file in Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference)
4. [Get direct download link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl())