# ViewPager with improved image quality

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-glide, android-viewpager2

I am using a **ViewPager** (with an ImageView) to display images, like a slide show gallery, for my Android app. I am using **Glide** to load the images from the external storage into the ViewPager, by using an Uri. However, the images loaded into the ViewPager have quite a poor quality (I enable zooming of the image, hence the reduced quality has an impact). On the other side, if I add `.override(SIZE_ORIGINAL, SIZE_ORIGINAL)`
to the Glide code, the image quality is good (because original size), however it takes much more time to load.

**Does anybody know an approach which allows to load an image into a ViewPager with a low resolution first (to enable fast loading), to then update the ViewPager with a better resolution picture shortly after?**

I have tried to reload the image with Glide twice, however, the image disappears for a short time in between, which is not ideal.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: Did you try different images for ViewPager items and zoomed items?

Comment: You could try using a placeholder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961710/using-glide-to-load-a-placeholder-from-url-to-display-while-loading-a-gif-andro